# Async Await not working on cloudinary - Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary to upload the image and after the image URL is returned from cloudinary, I want to send the URL to the backend and save it in my database. The problem is when i call using the cloudinary api, it is not waiting for the response to come back from cloudinary, it straight away goes to hit the backend URL after the cloudinary one. I have used async-await and promise also. But it is not working.

cloudinary.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
async uploadToCloudinary(data) {
    

    let url = `url`

    let config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
    };

    let image_url = axios.post(url, data, config).then(async res => {
        let data = await res.json();
        return data.secure_url
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)

    })

    return image_url
}
}
```

main.vue

```
    async process() {

  let formy = new FormData();
  formy.append("file", this.file);
  formy.append("upload_preset", 'abcde');

 let imageUrl = await cloudinary.uploadToCloudinary(formy)

  await dataService.sendToDatabase({ image: imageUrl.secure_url}).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })

}
```

Comment: You're using it the wrong way, and promises aren't chained correctly. Don't mix async/await and then together, they are different ways to write the same thing, and async/await is easier to write correctly

Comment: So what is `image_url` if it immediately returns?

Comment: image_url is empty. So the backend receives no image_url. It goes to backend when the response is not returned from cloudinary

Comment: `image_url` can't be empty, it should be a Promise. If `imageUrl` is empty, there's something wrong with the handling of the response data.

Answer (score 0):

Your promises are not properly chained. Mixing `async/await` and `then` together is not a good idea. Also, your image url parameter is not set. As a result, the image url is not passed to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Well you use `res.json()`. This is usually used with `fetch`. You dont need to do that on axios. You also dont need `async / await` at ur first function

```
import axios from "axios"
export default {
  uploadToCloudinary(data) {
    let url = `url`;
    let config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };
    return axios.post(url, data, config).then((res) => res.data.secure_url);
  },
};




async process() {
    let formy = new FormData();
    formy.append("file", this.file);
    formy.append("upload_preset", "abcde");

    let imageUrl = await cloudinary.uploadToCloudinary(formy);

    let response = await dataService.sendToDatabase({
      image: imageUrl.secure_url,
    });

    console.log(response);
  },
```